# discord.py throws error with on_member_join

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make an on_member_join function for a discord.py bot that sends a welcome message when someone joins my server.

This is the code I have for the function:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f"{member.name} JOINED!")
    welkomChannel = client.get_channel(channel id)
    await welkomChannel.send(f"Hello!")
```

When I join the server with an alt account, it throws this error: `discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired`. I went to discord.com/developers/applications and turned on the SERVER MEMBERS intent;

[image: SERVER MEMBERS INTENT]

And I added these lines to my code after the imports:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

So if I have enabled it on the website and I put the intents in the code, why does it still throw the error?

Comment: Can you include the full error traceback?

Answer (score 1):

```py
intents = discord.Intents()
intents.members = True
```

intents.Default basically includes presence, member, so you need to activate presence intents or change to Intents().

[docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.default)

Comment: I did write the id in the code, i just put "channel id" as an example here. I'll edit my post to add the whole error.

Comment: Please check edited answer